# Photo in my django database wont display

Tags: django, database

I am trying to display some images from my django database

Here are the models

```
class Problemspage(models.Model):
    problemname = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    difficultyproblem = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    difficultysolution = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = PythonCodeField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images', default='static/images')
```

and here are my views where I am using the Id of the problemname to call the name of the problem, e.g 'multiples of 3 and 5'

```
def viewproblem(request, problemnameId):
    context = {
    'title':'Problem ' + problemnameId,
    'data': allproblems,
    'name': Problemspage.objects.filter(id=problemnameId)
}
return TemplateResponse(request, 'app/viewproblem.html', context)
```

In my div I am trying to call that image

```
{% for nameofproblem in name %}
    <img src="{{ nameofproblem.photo.url }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

However I am getting an error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Even though the name of my images and the database are exactly the same. I have checked by copying and pasting the names so that they're identical.

Other questions related to this on stackoverflow have not been successful as

```
<img src="{{ nameofproblem.photo.url }}"/>
```

should have worked. It works fine if I call the image directly through static like this:

```
<img src="{% static 'images/Multiples_of_3_and_5.png' %}"/>
```

Note: the underscores don't matter, I have tried making everything with underscores (including in my database).

Comment: What have you set up to serve media files?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, i haven't set anything up? This is all I have done.